# How to retreive specific value from model using GET request (Laravel 10 )

Tags: php, laravel

I want to retrieve list of comments from my `CreateComments` model. I only want to retrieve the list of `Comments` from my data base using the GET request to the API.

Below are my controller, model & route classes (FYI there is already a route for the get request i want for testing purposes).

Controller class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\CreateComment;
use App\Models\BookRating;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class BookRatingController extends Controller
{
    
 

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function showComments()
    {
        return "This is the showComments method";
    } // return list of comments
    
        

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, BookRating $bookRating)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(BookRating $bookRating)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CreateComment extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'Comment',
        'userId',
        'bookId'
    ];
}
```

Route Class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BookRatingController;
use App\Http\Models\BookRating;
use App\Http\Models\CreateComment;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('CreateRating',[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateRating']);//adding a bookrating to database API -- POST METHOD-- 
Route::post('CreateComment',[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateComment']);

Route::get('showComments',[BookRatingController::class,'showComments']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `CreateComment` model has already been declared, you can use the below function in able to get all the comments.

This is using the eloquent way. Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#collections) for detailed explanation.

```
public function showComments() {
    $allComments = CreateComment::all();
    return $allCOmments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the comments

```
 public function showComments() {
    $comments = CreateComment::all();
    return view('your-view',compact('comments'));
}
```

If you want to get the specific user's comments then

```
   public function showComments($id) {
        $comments = CreateComment::where('userId',$id)->get();
        return view('your-view',compact('comments'));
    }
```

For this route might need some changings like

```
Route::get('showComments/{id}',[BookRatingController::class,'showComments']);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your future, delete the `CreateComment` model and call it `Comment` this cause `Create` is a action and not follow the standard naming convention.

Anyway to retrive all the Comments you shuld use the `all()` method

```
CreateComment::all();
```

If you want to get only one `CreateComment::find($id);` or better `CreateComment::findOrFail($id);`

From the moment that `CreateComment` seems to be relatated to a `Reservation`, you will need tyo prepare db and software to use relationship, couse one Reservation will have many Comments.

You can find many informations here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships

If you want to get an idea on how laravel work with the naming under the hood check this article: [laravel naming convention](https://medium.com/@laravelprotips/the-art-of-naming-in-laravel-a-simple-guide-c4e2dffd14df)

Comment: `CreateComment::get($id);` is wrong, and triggers an error `Unknown column '1'` (assuming `$id` is `1`). I think you meant `CreateComment::find($id);`

Comment: @TimLewis yes Tim I started to wrote how to get automatically the comment id via route::get and then I changed the idea